# Text justify didnt work

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

I took this and paste in a new android, with a few changed in other files, it didn't type anything in the applicatin, like this http://oi60.tinypic.com/2rw5lco.jpg ... does anyone know why?

```
package com.f.fa;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class PageAbus extends Activity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.abus);

       String text = "<html><body style=\"text-align:justify\"> %s </body></Html>";

       String data = "The power of theory lies in its ability to spare us from doing useless things. The power of theory lies in its ability to spare us from doing useless things.";

       WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.abussort);
       webView.loadData(String.format(text, data), "text/html", "utf-8");

    }

}
```

EDIT
Here is the xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#1d72c3"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:textStyle="italic" >

            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <WebView
                        android:id="@+id/abussort"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:textSize="21sp"
                        android:textStyle="italic" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </ScrollView>
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: That code works for me. Is there something wrong with your layout?

Comment: Mike M. I edit it and added the xml

Comment: Nope. Still works. Are you testing on a device or a an emulator?

Comment: I'm using device, the emulator stays for long

Answer (score 0):

You should add this permission in manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Check this [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html)